# Qunit _initProperties is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

I've run into some strange behavior here and wanted to see if anybody knew why it occurs. I've written a simple Ember QUnit test and want to share some data between each test, just to reduce clutter.

### Test

```
import Ember from 'ember'
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';

let create = Ember.Object.create;

let shared = create({});
shared.stardardData1 = create({ id: 1 });
shared.stardardData2 = create({ id: 2 });

moduleFor('controller:foo', 'description', {
    beforeEach() { ... }
    afterEach() { ... }
}

test('should do things', function () {
    let myGroup = [shared.standardData1, shared.standardData2];
}
```

A couple things here:

- I'm getting an error `this._initProperties is not a function`

  - The error goes away when I remove the shared stuff
  - The error persists if I add the shared stuff between the `moduleFor` and the `test`
- I want to be able to share variables defined in either the beforeEach or globally
- I've tried doing something like `let a = 1` in the `beforeEach`, but can't seem to reference them in the test itself

I noticed that the QUnit docs say that they've eliminated globals. Could that be playing a role in this? https://qunitjs.com/upgrade-guide-2.x/

PS: It would be nice to have something that set up the module just once instead of every time

### Edit

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Promise rejected before should do things: this._initProperties is not a function
Source:     

    TypeError: this._initProperties is not a function
        at create (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:46461:14)
        at Object.beforeEach (http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:185:20)
        at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6586:31
        at tryCatch (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:61631:14)
        at invokeCallback (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:61646:15)
        at publish (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:61614:9)
        at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:41408:7
        at invoke (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:11120:16)
        at Object.flush (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:11184:11)
        at Object.flush (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:10992:17)
```

Actually I think this might not have to do with the globals. I've also added (was not included before) `let create = Ember.Object.create` just to save some typing (and wrapped the above objects with the call `create(object)`. Getting rid of that and using the long form seems to get rid of this error though ...

Comment: They've eliminated globals means that they don't put their variables on `window` anymore, you should still be able to use shared data like this, I've done it many times before. You can also create another file in your test directory and store data inside that can be shared across multiple tests. Can you show how the function `_initProperties` is used and where its defined?

Comment: That's the question isn't it? It isn't mine and I'm having a tough time tracking it down. I'm guessing that it's buried deep in either the Ember or QUnit source code

Comment: Can you show the error stacktrace?

Comment: Also you should remove everything until the error doesn't happen, then slowly add line per line to narrow done the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of your question is the actual problem.

When you do

```
let create = Ember.Object.create
```

You extract the function `create` from the `Ember.Object` and create a new reference to it, as a plain function.

As per JS binding rules, when you call a function as a plain function, `this` inside of it binds to the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode). On the other hand, when you call a function as a method on an object (i.e. calling it directly on `Ember.Object`) would bind `this` to that object.

That's why `this` is undefined within `create` and hence `this._initProperties` is not a function.

Here's a demo of what is happening:

```js
// an object with a method
var obj = {
  getThis: function() {
    return this;
  }
};

// an extracted reference to the method
var extractedGetThis = obj.getThis;

// this binds to the object
console.log(
  obj.getThis() === obj // true
);

// this binds globally
console.log(
  extractedGetThis() === window // true
);
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @shane no problem, glad to help :)

Comment: For what it's worth, this should accomplish what I was looking for: `let create = Ember.Object.create.bind(Ember.Object)`